# Log cat in Reverse Chronological Order

Tags: android, logcat, eclipse-adt

Is there any way to make the Log cat entries in in Reverse Chronological Order?

Comment: I've Windows installation of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The `tac(1)` utility from the Debian / Ubuntu package `coreutils` can easily print files in reverse. `tac /path/to/log/file`

If you don't have `tac(1)` installed, perhaps you have `nl(1)`, `sort(1)`, and `cut(1)` installed; try `nl /path/to/log/file | sort -rn | cut -f2-`